# Why it counts these numbers so weird?

Tags: c, int, output

```
int height = 256;
int width = 256;
for(int i = 0; i<width*height; i++){
    int column = i-(width*(i/width));
    if(column < height/2){
        int number = i + width - 1 - column;
        printf("%d column %d number\n", column, number);
    }
    else i+=column-1;
}
```

Can someone explain why number is always same for every 256 numbers as shown in picture when it shouldnt be? And, if possible, how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: int column = i-(width*(i/width)); ?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. I get an error with the column[1]. It's not an array.

Comment: `else i+=column[1]-1;`...  `column` is not an array.  ( created here: `int column = i-(width*(i/width));` )

Comment: `i-(width*(i/width))` should just be `i % width`

Comment: For the first 256 values, `column` is always `i`, hence the expression `i + width - 1 - column` evaluates to `width - 1` which is `255` which is what is printed. If this is not what you expect, then state what you expect and provide compiling code.

Comment: Don't show pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: problem solved, I found mistake thanks to you guys.